# compare two string and get true if they have the same set of alphabet in python?

Tags: python, string

Suppose, we have two strings 
a = "hello"
b = "holel"

they have the same set of alphabet and what/ how the code should be if we want true if all the characters are present in the strings.[they both have same set of alphabet(non-recursive{eg: string1 = 'a' and string = 'aa' they should be same as there is one a in the first string and 2 a's in the second string})and instead of individually comparing each alphabet]

do we have to search the first index of string 1 and search all the indices of the string 2 continue the same process until the end of the string 1 ?....as python is the best in strings.Is there any simpler method to do so?

Comment: l = list(a); m = list(b); l.sort(); m.sort(); print l == m

Answer (score 3):

Use [set](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set)

```
>>> a = "hello"
>>> b = "holel"
>>> set(a)
set(['h', 'e', 'l', 'o'])
>>> set(b)
set(['h', 'e', 'l', 'o'])
>>> set(a) == set(b)
True
>>>
```